# golang panic - suppress & chain rules

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "testing"
)

// panic suppress,
func ExamplePanicSuppressed() {
    defer func() {
        fmt.Printf("%s: %v\n", "A", recover()) // catch panic(2)
    }()

    defer func() {
        panic(2) // suppress panic(1),
    }()
    panic(1)
    // Output:
    // A: 2
}

// panic chain - recover all,
func ExamplePanicChain_nestedRecoverAll() {
    defer func() {
        fmt.Printf("%s: %v\n", "A", recover()) // catch panic(1)
    }()

    defer func() {
        defer func() {
            fmt.Printf("%s: %v\n", "B", recover()) // catch panic(2)
        }()
        panic(2)
    }()
    panic(1)
    // Output:
    // B: 2
    // A: 1
}

// panic chain - recover partly,
func TestPanicChain_recoverPartly(t *testing.T) {
    f := func() {
        defer func() {
            defer func() {
                fmt.Printf("%s: %v\n", "B", recover()) // catch panic(2)
            }()
            panic(2)
        }()
        panic(1) // won't catch, will panic,
    }

    assert.Panics(t, f) // panic(1) will panic, thus true,
}
```

I wrote above test trying to figure out when a panic is stacked/chained, when it's suppressed.

**Summary** - from above test (*draft*):

1. suppress
   if deferred function panic again, without recover, then new panic will suppress the old one,
2. chain
   if deferred function panic again, but recover in nested defer, then will recover new panic first, then the old panic still exists,

**Questions:**

- Are the above summary correct? If not, please correct & explain.

Comment: [1/2] I would reiterate what icza said in his respective answer I linked to: you do not need to "explore" what Go does with multiple `defer`ed calls and "nested" panics as the Go's languae spec is very easy to read (compared to something monstrous like C++'s): first you read on [`defer`s](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements) and then on [handling panics](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Handling_panics), where the key statement is «If D returns normally, without starting a new panic, the panicking sequence stops» (there, D is a deferred function which calls `recover()`–"catching" the panic).

Comment: [2/2] Basically from that statement it follows, that if a deferred functions start a new panic, there occurs another panicking sequence which means calling all the deferred functions up the call stack.